# .net code from xsd - specify the name of the created property

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have the following xsd:

```
<xs:element name="Person" type="PersonType">
    <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> This will be my person class</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="id" minOccurs="1"  >
         <xs:annotation>
             <xs:appinfo>
                 <property name="PersonID"/>
             </xs:appinfo>
         </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="description" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="id" type="char40"/>
<xs:element name="description" type="char255"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char40">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="char255">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I am generating a .net class based on this xsd (using xsd.exe right now).

The generated Person class will have a property called **id**, but I would like that the property would be called **PersonID** .

I cannot change the name of the xml tag as I'm using the xsd as communication contract and the tags are fixed.

Yet I would like to have more control on how the generated code looks.
**What are my options?**

Right now the only valid option seems to be writing my own code generator that would handle the *appinfo* tags according to my needs - but I would like this to be my last option (as I feel that I'm not the first to have this problem, so there must be other solutions out there).

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: (1) Look into [Xsd2Code](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=xsd2code&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxsd2code.codeplex.com%2F&ei=RvlPT96gO4mwhAfKzY31Cw&usg=AFQjCNEWpYZf0IX18XcxjZJJSoJ8uhkj5Q&sig2=vUKfpMBvFoGX4MFcBy84KQ) which offers a lot more flexibility than xsd.exe. (2) Consider inheriting the auto-generated class and exposing new Properties as you see fit.